# Batch (.bat) file with timer that wil shutdown computer if password is not entered

Tags: batch-file

I used this code that I found and modified:

```
@echo off
echo This PC will shut down in 30 seconds. Press CTRL+C to abort.
ping -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul
shutdown /s
```

The only problem is that I can just exit out of it so I need it that even if it is exited, it will shut down anyway.

So, what I need is a (bat.) file that will shut down the computer after 20 seconds unless the password is entered. If someone closes the application or exits it, then the countdown will continue and eventually shut down.

Comment: You won't be able to do that with a batch file. Further to this, any program (not just batch) can be exited by using Task Manager. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It is not quite impossible, but definitely not fool proof. There are ways around it though to force it to shutdown, regardless of user actions, but I consider that as hacking and will not post that here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not fool proof. But try doing it the other way around.

Shutdown with a timeout. If a password is entered, then abort shutdown.(in this case the password is `mypassword`). So even if the cmd window is closed, it will shutdown.

```
@echo off
Set "passw=mypassword"
Shutdown /s /t 20 >nul
echo This PC will shut down in 20 seconds.
Set /p "pss=Enter Password to abort: "
If "%pss%"=="%passw%" shutdown /a
```

Keep in mind that this can still be canceled by opening `cmd` and running `shutdown /a` to abort.

Comment: Hey Gerhard, The code works great and exiting still shuts down. However, when i type "pss" or "mypassword" the shutdown still activates. Is there something I am doing wrong or do i need to change some parts?

Comment: @JD Sorry, forgot to add `%` for the variables. please copy the code and try again. the password is `mypassword`

Comment: If `Shutdown` is used like this, you should really use a reason code to prevent the system from logging the event as unplanned. You could also negate the `Echo` command by using the `/C` option? i.e. `Shutdown /S /T 20 /C "Pending SHUTDOWN in 20 seconds . . . ." /D U:0:0`

Comment: Ok so i put the % in but it still shut down and they may be in the wrong area, so could you show me whete they go (full script).

Comment: Did you copy everything in my script after the edit? Please copy the entire script and try it.

Comment: Yes but i think i am putting the % in the wrong area, where do they go?

Comment: I got this@echo off
Set "passw=%mypassword%"
Shutdown /s /t 20 >nul
echo This PC will shut down in 20 seconds.
Set /p "pss=Enter Password to abort: "
If "pss"=="%passw%" shutdown /a

Comment: @JD No. Last line is wrong. Should be`if "%pss%"=="%passw%" shutdown /a`

Comment: Still is not working, here is what its looking like:@echo off
Set "passw=%mypassword%"
Shutdown /s /t 20 >nul
echo This PC will shut down in 20 seconds.
Set /p "pss=Enter Password to abort: "
if "%pss%"=="%passw%" shutdown /a

Comment: @JD Come on dude... You keep changing the code. Please COPY the code in my answer EXACTLY and post it in your file. nowhere did I say to add `%` in this line. `set "passw=%mypassword%"` nor is it like that in my code.

Comment: Yup, what i did was i was trying to figure out why it wasnt working at the start and that was the wrong file code, works all good now thanks my dude